# Capture form submission via jquery code

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the follow html form, where your submit action is handled by jQuery code:

```
<form method="post" action="cad_usuario.html" id="target">      
    <p><input type="hidden" name="id_usuario"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>       
    <p><input type="text" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>
    <p><input type="text" name="pnome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>
    <p><input type="text" name="unome" placeholder="Ultimo Nome" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>
    <p>
      <select name="tipo">
        <c:forEach var="tipo" items="${tipos}">
            <option value="<c:out value="${tipo.id}"/>"> <c:out value="${tipo.nome}"/> </option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </p>

    <c:forEach var="item2" items="${campos}">
        <p><input type="text" name="${item2.campo}" placeholder="${item2.campo}" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>
    </c:forEach>

    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn_cadastra">Cadastrar</button></p>
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn_altera">Alterar</button></p>
</form>
```

The jquery code is:

```
<script>
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {       
      // Stop form from submitting normally
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get some values from elements on the page:
      var $form = $( this ),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

      // Send the data using post
      var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );

      // Put the results in a div
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#result_3").show();
        $( "#result_3" ).empty().append( data );
        $("#result_3").hide(5000);
        if(url == "edit_usuario.html") {
            $("#btn_form").val("Cadastrar");
            $("#title").empty().append("<strong>Novo</strong> Cadastre um novo usuario.");
            $("#target").attr("action", "cad_usuario.html");​
        }
      });
});  
</script>
```

My problem is, despite this code supposed to capture the return and save in the variable **posting**, to append to a  identified by id "result_3", this is not happening, and the response is display in a new page. How i can fix that, to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after publish this question, I solve the problem, Apparently, an invalid character in the end of one of the lines of code cause problems for the execution of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your code is never being called. You may need to put your code in a `$(document).ready()` block or otherwise make sure that the event is wired up after the browser has parsed the DOM. To make sure that your code is being called, add a `debugger` line as your first line in the function.

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {       
   // Stop form from submitting normally
   debugger;
```

Open your browser's developer tools and click the submit button. If your code is called then the browser will "break" on the `debugger` line and you'll be able to step through your code to find the problem.